# Anylogic Time measure in system

Tags: anylogic, time-measurement

I am looking to measure and aggrigate all the time (in minutes) that all the agents spend in my queueing model. Afterwards I want to multiply the time by a factor. Is this possible?

So overall I am looking at two problems:

1. Reading out my time measure in a way that returns me time units for individual agents
2. Multiplying these values with a factor to arrive at the final result

Any help will be highly appreciated!

What I tried:

I already looked at the help pages, but couldnt find anything.

I know that time measure start and end are needed and i created a histogram, but can I access the individual time entires and automaticially calculate with them or do I have to manually read out the logs?

I also tried to link my time measure to a dataset, as I believe it should be the key in solving this problem, however I cant get the syntax to work.

Again thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You actually ask *several* questions at once. Please split these into several, separate questions. This helps you and others in the future with similar problems. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help . Also, aadd screenshots, make *our* lives easy. PS: Anything is possible in AnyLogic :)